# recursive sequence generation (haskell function)

Tags: haskell, recursion

Given below is a small haskell function used to generate a recursive sequence. I'm getting a type error while using floor function. floor function is expecting RealFrac, I suppose. The code and error are given below.

```
main = do
    print( funSeq 9)

funSeq n = do 
    if (n<4)
        then 1
        else floor ((funSeq (n-1) + funSeq (n-2)) * (funSeq (n-3)/ funSeq(n-4)))
```

Error:

```
No instance for (RealFrac a0) arising from a use of 'funSeq'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one easy solution is to put a few `fromIntegral`s in there:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print( funSeq 9)

funSeq :: Int -> Int
funSeq n = do 
    if (n<4)
        then 1
        else floor (fromIntegral (funSeq (n-1) + funSeq (n-2)) * (fromIntegral (funSeq (n-3)) / fromIntegral (funSeq(n-4))))
```

which gives

```
λ> :main
78
```

---

trying to tidy this up a bit:

```
funSeq :: Int -> Int
funSeq n
  | n < 4 = 1
  | otherwise = floor $
      (fromIntegral $ funSeq (n-1) + funSeq (n-2))
      * (fromIntegral . funSeq $ n-3) / (fromIntegral . funSeq $ n-4)
```

but it's a bit hard to see what you are trying to - what is the expected type for your `funSeq` (which is no sequence ;) )?

Comment: its is just a function which takes in Int and returns Int.

Comment: i'm having some indentation problem i guess. its showing parse error on |

Comment: did it compile for you ?

Comment: sorry for the delay - aside from a compiler warning (the `/`) - both versions are correct for me (and return `78`)